# IdentityServer4 and calling a custom function

Tags: c#, identityserver4

What I'm trying to achieve is this: set up an instance of IdentityServer4 that hands off authentication of a username/password to a function located in another .net assembly. I understand that OpenID Connect is one option but coming up with a custom IdP gives the impression of making a mountain out of a molehill.

Are there any simple ways of achieving this using Identityserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` you need to register your own implementations of `IProfileService` and `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`. For example:

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

The `ValidatedAsync` method on the `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` is where you can then access the username/password and call your own assemblies for validation. You then return a `GrantValidationResult` object from that method to indicate success/failure. 
For example:

```
public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        logWriter.Debug("Validating resource owner password: " + context.UserName);
        if (_userRepository.ValidatePassword(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(context.UserName, "password");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        logWriter.Debug("Unauthorised resource owner password for: " + context.UserName);
        return Task.FromResult(new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.UnauthorizedClient));
    }
```

The `IProfileService` is where you can set the claims on the context, for example by examining what has been requested (as defined in the `ApiResource` definition) and then make your own calls to whichever assemblies/repo you need to find out the details for those claims.